# stream large file upload into database using pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, large-files, pg-promise

I would like to allow my users to upload large files <1GB to my database. I am using a database since storing raw files can be dangerous and I would like to have a single source of state in my system since its meant to be serverless.
Now the VPS am I am planning to run it on has limited ram. And multiple users should of course be able to upload simultaneously.
So in order to not exceed this ram, I would need to either

- stream the image into the database as it is being uploaded from user
- or I would need to first stream it into a file using something like multer and then stream it from the file into PostgreSQL as a BLOB

So is there a way to do this using pg-promise? Stream a file into the database without ever loading the whole thing into ram?

Comment: There is no such thing as streaming into an individual `BLOB`, not in `pg-promise`, not in any other library, because PostgreSQL doesn't have such feature. You are effectively misusing the database for what it is. You just do not put large files into a PostgreSQL itself, that's the wrong thinking.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605922/are-there-performance-issues-storing-files-in-postgresql).

Comment: I mean fundamentally a database is for holding data. I don't understand why everyone seams to think that larger units of data belong into a different storage system. Its just one more thing to manage. But I guess I'll just stick with a fs solution for now, thanks

Comment: Only an external file storage will let you to actually stream files in. So it will scale a heck better.